# How to have a DIV appear after you hover over an image/link/another div?

Tags: html, css

I have done this before, but sadly I have forgotten. I did it with simple CSS, so no javascript or jquery should be used. All I want is for A to be showing, and for B to show when you hover over A.

Also, if you could, after you show me how to do the above could you also show me how to use a sliding animation on the hidden div? So when you hover over A, B slides in?

Comment: .hi {display:None;} a:hi {display:visible;} or something like that.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? If you want animations, there are CSS3 transforms which only IE9 and modern versions of Firefox and Safari support, so you'll be better off with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some pure CSS that will not work in IE 6. It involves wrapping a container `#outer` around both the link and box (`#tooltip`). Of course, in a real application, you will probably want to position the box using absolute positioning.

```
#tooltip {
    display: none;
}

#outer:hover #tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

And the HTML ([try it](http://jsfiddle.net/T75Kg/)):

```
<div id="outer">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png">
    <div id="tooltip">Hello, world!</div>
</div>
```

For animations, you are best off using jQuery or another JS library because browser support for CSS3 animations is currently rather poor.

Comment: Thanks this worked charms! Any direction you can point me into adding an animation? Thanks!

Comment: Hey could you take a look at my new question please, if its not any trouble? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565778/slide-div-horizontally-from-off-screen-to-center