# Slide div horizontally from off screen to center?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

This is the javascript used in the gayadesign tabs

```
var TabbedContent = {
    init: function() {  
        $(".tab_item").mouseover(function() {

          var background = $(this).parent().find(".moving_bg");

          $(background).stop().animate({
            left: $(this).position()['left']
        }, {
            duration: 300
        });

        TabbedContent.slideContent($(this));

    });
},

slideContent: function(obj) {

    var margin = $(obj).parent().parent().find(".slide_content").width();
    margin = margin * ($(obj).prevAll().size() - 1);
    margin = margin * -1;

    $(obj).parent().parent().find(".tabslider").stop().animate({
        marginLeft: margin + "px"
    }, {
        duration: 300
    });
}
}

$(document).ready(function() {
TabbedContent.init();
});
```

How do I implement that into the provided HTML?

I am trying to imitate this: http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/tabbed/

```
<body>

{block:Posts}

<div id="outer">
{block:Photo}
<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/zIrle9bek/block.png">
<div id="tooltip">

<div class="photo">
{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />{LinkCloseTag}
</div>
{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}

</div>
{/block:Photo}
</div>

{/block:Posts}
</body>
```

Comment: To display code literally (and have it highlighted), indent each line with four spaces (or select it and click the **{ }** button above).

Comment: Oh that would have helped when I signed up. Thanks Bolt!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you pointed us to a link for a script...   have you tried looking at that script?  I doubt if you can't make sense of the script itself, then you're **probably** not going to get the complete answer you are wanting.

Comment: Well what I actually did before this, is I tried actually using that script and that HTML to put each post in. It didn't work because I wanted a seperate tab for each post, and what it would do is put all photo posts (or any post for that matter) in one tab. So if I put Photo in X div it would put all Photo posts in that div. Same goes for text/link/video/music etc.. I actually thought about doing that, and I will, but I just thought maybe it would be better to start from scratch. I'll take a look at it and tell you what I find.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery's [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function can animate any arbitrary CSS property.

For instance:

```
$('#item1').animate({left: '+=50px'});
```

Will move `#item1` 50px to the right. You can use absolute numbers like `'50px'` if you wish.

Comment: How would I do that on mouseover of the image?

Comment: That looks great but my problem is I need each post to have its own tab. So if you put the tags for say a photo post in one div that correlates with the first tab, ALL photo posts will show up in that tab. I need to have each in its own tab. Thats why I was building from scratch.

Comment: What Tumblr does is each post has its own "Block" so Photo = {block:Photo} Text = {block:Text} Link = {block:Link} and so on. So the way you have a post show up on a page is to put that block tage into a div. If you put {block:Photo} into the div that says "Hello, World!" on your example, every single photo post for that page will show up in that div. What I want is for every photo post, text, link, music, video, etc to have its own tab and its own div.

Comment: Roseannebarr.tumblr.com has each post seperateley (right now I have only coded for photo posts, but you get the idea.)